# Using return in a function to assign a choice value in a menu

Tags: python, function, return

How can I use the `choice` variable in my `menu()` function to return the choice to my while loop?

```
def menu():
    print("MENU")
    print("1) Test")
    print("2) Quit")
    choice = int(input("\nChoose an option : "))
    return choice

while choice != 2 :
    menu()
    if choice == 1 :
        do_this
    elif choice == 2 :
        print("This program will terminate.") 
        break
else :
    print("Invalid option... ")
```

Comment: `choice = menu()` before using the `choice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply do it like this

```
def menu():
    print("MENU")
    print("1) Test")
    print("2) Quit")
    choice = int(input("\nChoose an option : "))
    return choice

while choice != 2 :
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1 :
        do_this
    elif choice == 2 :
        print("This program will terminate.") 
        break
else :
    print("Invalid option... ")
```

You are getting the return value in your while loop with the variable choice in the line `choice = menu()` Then you can use that value in your while loop.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! :)